# Better GPS accuracy in Android application

Tags: gps, android, accuracy, mobile-gis

We are looking for ways to read higher GPS accuracy (less than 1 m) in our Android application.

We have tried with couple of mobiles having L1 frequency and supports GPS , GLONASS, Galileo etc but the gpstest application gives around 4m accuracy. I have read couple of blogs and they suggest using a better handheld hardware including L5 and dual frequency support.

Is there any ways for APIservices/hardware-integration/bluetooth-integration/code-changes through which we can desired GPS accuracy in our Android application.

Comment: can you do way-point averaging?

Comment: Dual Band (L1+L5) is the better route (more so in urban environments) but not many devices have the broadcom gps chipset currently. https://www.androidauthority.com/dual-frequency-gps-878169/

Comment: Yes, duel frequency phones seems to return better results as per blogs. Is it possible to make use of the underneath technology of duel frequency phones in android app by native API's or its just the GeoLocation of android that we can use by relying on the hardware.

Comment: @nmtoken .. Is it about taking multiple locations at the same point and then taking avg of it ?

Comment: Yes, at the same location for a period of time, and then repeated over a number of times (different times of the day), different days

Comment: This is for a survey based application and it is not feasible for my users to perform this test at this frequency at the same location.

Answer (score 1):

See "How to get one-meter location-accuracy from Android devices (Google I/O '18)" by Google:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vywGgSrGODU

It discusses use of carrier-phase measurements on Android. Requires that user turns off "duty-cycling" in developer settings, which requires Android 9 Pie or higher.

The presentation text is available at: https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/

Android devices that support raw GNSS measurements list is at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss

Comment: Thanks ! I will try to implemement the GNSS Measurement API and will revert back with the results.